# GCM stuck on register on 2.3.3 Gingerbread device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-2.3-gingerbread

For some reason, using "GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);" works on 4.0 + devices.
However, it stuck at the following message without getting anymore GCM notification from Google.

"**Registering app (my package) of senders (my api #)**"

1) manifest and receiver should be correct since it's working on 4.2.1.

2) I have google play and linked with google account on 2.3.3 device

I have searched for several day and couldn't find an answer.
Anyone know what's wrong or have the same issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out it's just because I didn't set the receiver's category correctly.

Since I was putting all my source code in a library project and referencing it with each individual application, I need to rename 3 different places in the manifest.

1)

```
<permission
        android:name="digital.dispatch.mobilebooker.base.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

to

```
   <permission
        android:name="digital.dispatch.mobilebooker.(my app name).permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

2)

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="digital.dispatch.mobilebooker.base.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

to

3)

```
<category android:name="digital.dispatch.mobilebooker.base" />
```

to

```
   <category android:name="digital.dispatch.mobilebooker.(my app name)" />
```

The reason why it worked in 4.0 + device is because I only did the first two but not 3).
Since 4.0+ device doesn't care about receiver's category, it worked.
However, when I am testing on 2.3.3 device, the category actually matters and causing it not receiving any response.

Hope this will help any other that encounter the same situation.

Comment: Thanks for submitting your own solution.  I had the same problem!

Comment: My problem was within category.